# Recording an entire row of cells (with references to other cells) automatically when I change the referenced cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have formulas that I need to change that have outputs and solutions. I have created an entire row `A46:CV42` that shows every effected Value (formulas solution) in each cell. What I need is to record every single change to that entire row automatically every time any cell value is changed. Be it on the same sheet below it in recurring rows or on another sheet.

I have tried some things I have found but they all deal with individual cells being changed or when you manually change data.

Example of what I've tried. I am a novice in this area.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        a = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & a).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if you want row `46` or row `42`. Please see below an approach, and comments in the code for further details:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim wsWatch As Worksheet: Set wsWatch = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'declare and set the sheet (change the name or use Target.Worksheet instead as needed)
    Dim rngWatch As Range: Set rngWatch = wsWatch.Range("A46:CV46") 'declare and set the range to watch over
    Dim arrWatch As Variant: arrWatch = rngWatch 'allocate the range to an array

    Dim wsHistory As Worksheet: Set wsHistory = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") 'declare and set the sheet
    With wsHistory
        Dim lRow As Long: lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row in the history
        Dim rngHistory As Range: Set rngHistory = .Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, 100)) 'declare and set the range of the last populated row (last historic change)
    End With
    Dim arrHistory As Variant: arrHistory = rngHistory 'allocate the range to an array

    Dim C As Long

    'Only one row in the arrays, let's loop over the columns
    For C = LBound(arrWatch, 2) To UBound(arrWatch, 2) 'for each column in the ranges
        If arrWatch(1, C) <> arrHistory(1, C) Then 'if there is a mismatch
            rngHistory.Offset(1) = rngWatch.Value 'allocate the values in the next free row
            Exit For 'exit here if mismatch found
        End If
    Next C
End Sub
```

This might not be the ideal solution, but i'm looking forward to see other solutions... meanwhile, I think it does what you've asked.

Comment: 1st Sheet is Sheet 1- need to record to Sheet 2
Do I need to "set an array" myself or have you done it there?
46 was correct my error.
For row setting can I set it as indefinite or open ended?
Much of this is over my head.

Comment: Is all done in there, place this in the `Sheet1` code part and restart the workbook... Give it a try and let me know if it behaves a s expected.

Comment: It is working. If I have want to update the sheet name with special characters  I can just change this line correct?
Dim wsWatch As Worksheet: Set wsWatch = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 
to
Dim wsWatch As Worksheet: Set wsWatch = wb.Sheets("Results&Solutions") 
Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. Or see code comment for alternative `Target.Worksheet` will pickup the sheet where the code is running.

Comment: Okay so Input 'Target.Worksheet' In place of 'sheet1'
You have saved me tremendous amounts of time thank you.

Comment: Instead of `Set wsWatch = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")` can use `Set wsWatch = Target.Worksheet` . No problems, glad it works.

Comment: Helped a very large amount. Wondering how to tag you directly if I have another question? Would love your input on it.

Comment: You can use @DarXyde and add the link (here) ... unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a system of private messages here, but can drop me an email at DarXyde [ at ] Gmail [dot] com , and if i can help... i will.

Comment: Sent! Thanks @DarXyde